How to stop bash (dnf) from looking for potential package?
Whenever I mistype some command like clea instead of clear, bash tries to find potential packages that might have this command, and suggests installing it if available.
I do not want this to happen, since it takes quite a while to lookup, and I want the process to terminate immediately so that I can use my terminal again.
Is there a workaround for this?


https://superuser.com/q/1533599/105002

@choroba that is neat!

That's a feature that your linux distro probably initializes for you in the global bash config. You can disable it for your current shell by removing the handler that does that:
unset -f command_not_found_handle

You can also add that line to your bashrc (~/.bashrc, create it if it doesn't exist yet).
